# "Unexpected token" syntax error in function definition

Tags: function, shell, unix

I'm new to shell scripting and am trying to run a simple script with a function in it. I keep getting an error message relating to my use of `echo`. Can anybody tell me how to fix this error?

Here's the code:

```
function functionA{
    echo "FunctionA is executing!!"
}
functionA
```

Here is the error message on the command line:

```
function1: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
function1: line 4: `    echo "FunctionA is executing!!"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `()` after function names:

```
function functionA() {
    echo "FunctionA is executing!!"
}
```

Comment: Assuming the `function` keyword is supported, the parentheses should be optional. More likely, the space before the opening `{` is the solution.